# Warden authentication recalls 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

i tried setting up devise with a brand new rails app, i have devise installed correctly using the gemfile and bundle install

following that installed devise using rails generate devise:install

created a new model using rails generate devise user

rake db:migrate to create the user table

added  `devise_for :users do
    get 'users/sign_out', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end` for signing out with my browser

run rails server

go to localhost:3000/users/sign_up  to create a new user

go to localhost:3000/users/sign_out to log him out

go to localhost:3000/users/sign_in and try to log him in again and fails with the following and sending me back to the login screen without being logged in

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-13 16:55:28 +0800
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cbFEP0FJ/e2XYHfub3ZeI7nEX0nCheXzCDs2ner3Zw8=", "newuser"=>{"email"=>"henghong.lee@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cbFEP0FJ/e2XYHfub3ZeI7nEX0nCheXzCDs2ner3Zw8=", "newuser"=>{"email"=>"henghong.lee@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Rendered /Users/Kinnovate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views/devise/shared/_links.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered /Users/Kinnovate/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 175ms (Views: 16.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

how do i fix Completed 401 Unauthorized ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
attr_accessor :password
```

seemed to be the cause of the problem, because of that devise does not seem to create an encrypted password for the model

Comment: So how exactly did you fix this issue?

Comment: My problem turned out to be with RefineryCMS - I needed a separate model which uses devise for users membership. The problem was that I had to include `config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]` in `config/devise.rb` since Refinery overrides that and everything worked fine for me now.